# Non-Trivial Data-Query in Grails

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

imagine the following problem in grails

you have some kind of audit trail domain class with numeric properties. For instance a class in which the current burndown value of your scrum project is written:

```
class burndown {
    Date createDate
    int  value
}
```

Your projects uses this class to store the current burndown value each time you update a task - this means several times a day.

Now you want to plot a diagram with the last stored value **for each day**.

An SQL statement for this could look something like

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table 
where 
  id in (
    select 
      max(id) 
    from 
      table 
    group by 
      TO_CHAR(create_date,'yyyyddmm')
  )
```

Now my question: how do you do such a query in grails?

If I have to use such an SQL statement, how to I avoid to put the table and column names hard coded in the statement?

PS: this code hasn't been tested. just written down from my mind... but I guess you feel what I want to ask

Comment: You probably mean: `(select max(id) from table group by...)`, right?

Comment: btw: I know, I should aggregate the data in another table in order not to run into performance problems...

Comment: Another thing: If the `create_date` field is of type `date` and not datetime, you don't need the conversion to char. You can safely `GROUP BY create_date` and the query will be able to use an index on `(create_date)` or `(create_date, id)` and run efficiently.

Comment: Putting aggregated data in another table is off course another option, **when** the table will grow huge and the query slower than accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you'll most likely want to rename `createDate` to `dateCreated` since it's automatically set for you by Grails if you use that name, so you only need to specify values for the 'real' properties of the class. It's not important to this issue though.

If you want the most recent item by created date, there are a few different ways you could do this but I think this makes the most sense:

```
def mostRecent = Burndown.listOrderByDateCreated(max: 1, order: 'desc')[0]
```

or if you retain your name

```
def mostRecent = Burndown.listOrderByCreateDate(max: 1, order: 'desc')[0]
```

This is described at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ - it's a fine manual, worthy of reading.

Comment: ok. Got the dateCreated wrong from memory (should do so much copy&paste). But I guess your solution only returns the most recent item. I would like to get the last entry for each day :-) so a big list with only one entry per day...

Comment: Try `def mostRecentPerDay = Burndown.executeQuery('from Burndown where id in (select max(id) from Burndown group by cast(dateCreated as date))')`

Comment: `cast(dateCreated as date)` still takes the time into account. So I have to use `TO_CHAR(create_date,'yyyyddmm')`

Answer (score 1):

Not a Grails user, so below should be corrected accordingly by a Grails'ist

If domains are related, try something like:

```
Foo.findAllInList(Bar.list([group:'create_date']))
```

Comment: I guess a group is not enough since it does not guarantee that I get the last item of each day (sorry, just added the max(id) in my question)

Comment: Burt works for Spring and is a Grails "heavy" so I would defer to him on this. Have you considered adding order:'create_date' to the map param? That "should" group & order and get the last item per day. Might as well create a couple of simple test domains and run the suggestions here (adding "loggingSql = true" to applicable closure in dataSources config to verify generated sql is not only close to what you would have written by hand, but also not loading the entire DB ;--))